# IntelliJ and Apache Jena throws strange Exception

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, semantic-web, intellij-14

I'm currently working on an Semantic Web Project using Apache Jena Library in Java. Today I wanted to try IntelliJ instead of Eclipse as IDE until a strange error occured: While debugging the executin of a Query, the following exception was thrown:

```
Method threw 'com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.ARQException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.toString()
```

In Eclipse, everything works perfect without any issues. Has anyone an idea?! Did I setup something wrong in IntelliJ (Ultimate 14.1.2)? I'm working on Java SDK 1.7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you used Eclipse, did you use the Eclipse compiler too?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to change Eclipse Java Compiler?! Unter Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler I can only set JDK Compliance level. In IntellJ, I didn't change the Java Compiler from the default.

Comment: `IntelliJ > Settings > Compiler > Java Compiler > Use compiler > Eclipse` - see if this makes any difference.  The toString of QueryEngineHTTP can throw exceptions, so you should put a breakpoint in there too.

Comment: Actually this didnt't change anything. I'm currently concerned that It could be some Windows network-right issue (maybe firewall) because on my laptop at home IntelliJ behaves just like it should but on the Workstation it does not perform all queries on the RDF server succesfully :(

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?